# Errors installing apache-airflow on Windows

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to install apache-airflow

`pip install apache-airflow==1.10.10`

and got errors.

```
am Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/spt_setup.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/spt_setup.obj
  spt_setup.c
  src/spt_setup.c(23): warning C4273: '__p__environ': inconsistent dll linkage
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdlib.h(1165): note: see previous definition of '__p__environ'
  src/spt_setup.c(459): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for setproctitle
Failed to build setproctitle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for setproctitle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Could you please help

Comment: Please try to upgrade pip and wheel using `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and try again

Comment: @tbhaxor I did it and try again and I got the same error

Comment: I have resolved it I change pip version to 20.2.3 'pip install pip==20.2.3' + 'pip install setproctitle==1.1.9' and got the success.

Answer (score 2):

After installing `Visual Studio Build Tools` component `C++ build tools` didn't help (led to compilation errors in `setproctitle` setup), I tried downgrading `setproctitle`, similar to what the OP did in his comment...

The following install worked for me on Windows:

```cmd
pip install "setproctitle>=1.1.0,<1.2.0"
pip install pytest-filter-subpackage
pip install pytest-cov
pip install "pygments>=2.6.0,<3.0.0"
pip install apache-airflow
```

(This installs latest version of apache-airflow (currently 2.x))

---

For lower version of airflow i.e.

```cmd
pip install "apache-airflow>=1.0.0,<2.0.0"
```

you will **also** need

```cmd
pip install "marshmallow>=2.18.0,<3.0.0"
```

OR

```cmd
pip install flask-appbuilder --upgrade
```